# Should I tell my new boss about my past performance under my old boss?

Tags: management, performance-reviews

Review season is around the corner, woohoo! */sarcasm*

So long story short I've been working under a new boss on a new team for a few months now. Not by choice. Initially I was reluctant, but I'm now settling in quite nicely. To be honest, I went through a few personal problems in the past year or so and my performance was weak under my old boss. I know this. He knows this. I'm surprised I wasn't given any kind of "performance improvement plan" when I was working under him on a big project. At the end of the day though, our project was completed and we got it to production for our business users.

I'd say that my performance is a lot better now under my new boss. Mainly because I'm a lot happier as a person, and I'm liking his overall management style as compared to my old one. The problem is that he's only seen my work for the past three months. He's definitely going to talk to my old boss about my performance in the last year and I'm certainly not optimistic about what my old boss will say. Another thing is that I had worked with another colleague on this big project (we were both leads), but given the fact that I went through personal issues,  I let my work slide. I'm sure my colleague knows that I didn't carry my weight during this project, but I'm not exactly sure of the sentiments he has towards me. One of the requirements of the review process is that we must ask at least a few other colleagues to give us peer reviews. It'd be natural for me to get a review from him but, again, I'm not expecting a positive outcome out of this. I could avoid asking him all together but frankly I don't know else I would ask because the majority of my work and interaction has been with him in the past year.

Should I tell my new boss upfront about these issues, or should I let things play out as they should? Never in my professional life have I gotten a negative review, but I'm expecting something as such this time around. What sucks is that I probably won't be getting a bonus this year because of that. This is all negative thinking and assumptions being made obviously, but I'm wondering if there's an effective way to approach this in order to maximize a positive outcome out of this, and ultimately a better raise(?) or better bonus(?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely **not**.

[Take it from Dr. Melfi](https://twitter.com/TheSopranoQuote/status/353906886090825729?s=09) from *The Sopranos*:

> "People see only what you allow them to see."

Earn your reputation with your new boss on the merits of your future actions; not based on what transpired with another boss.

---

People will say what they will say regardless of what you say to your boss upfront. Don't worry about playing defense because it's futile. Keep moving forward and do your work to the best of your ability. Everything else will sort itself out.

Comment: +1 I see no benefit to bringing it up. A good (IMHO) boss won't particularly care.  You work for them now and you're doing well.  What you did for your last boss, whether that boss was at this company or another company, is almost completely meaningless.  A bad boss might make a big deal out of it to save money and not give you the raise you deserver.  Telling a boss like that about it ahead of time won't stop them from holding it against you, and you may get lucky and they don't find out.